# How can I check the remaining size of a persistent disk on Google Cloud? And where can I find the code in the instances?

Tags: postgresql, gcloud

I created a project on Google Cloud a long time ago and I am currently having some problems with it. The only result I seem to be receiving is `Internal Server Error`.

I tried connecting to the compute instance through ssh, but it does not help much because :

- as far as I remember, I used to be able to see all the code on the compute instance. It's no longer there, the home folder only has some hidden files. I am not sure where to look for the actual project files.
- the only error I managed to get from a log file was : `Error syncing pod 9c8e56bc-4298-11e6-ab50, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "postgres" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=postgres pod=postgres_default(9c8e56bc-4298-11e6-ab50)`; this makes me think there are some issues with Postgres, which has a persistent disk to its own, but there seems to be no easy way to find out how much of that disk is occupied.
- even though I am admin on that project and I should receive detailed (with stacktrace) emails every time there is an error, I am not receiving anything at all.

This behaviour started today, all of a sudden, and I haven't touched the project in almost 2 years, so I am completely lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Try deleting and recreating the pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check the remaining size of a persistent disk on Google
>   Cloud?

For this part, I finally found a way to do it today. I'll describe it all here with print screens so that it is easy for anyone.

1. First, go to the Google Console, Disks page : https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disks
2. Identify the persistent disk you are interested in. In my case, this was called `pg-data-disk`. Click on the respective VM instance; this will be on the column "In use by", link in the image below :
   [image]
3. This will open a SSH connection to the VM instance to which your persistent disk is attached. In the SSH window, run the following command : `sudo lsblk`. The result should be like in the image below :
   [image]
4. You will thus discover the DISK ID (in my case this was `sdb`), so you can now run : `sudo df -h <YOUR DISK ID>`. This command will give you the exact disk usage, as shown below :
   [image]

As for the other part of the question, I was actually using Docker containers which were orchestrated by Kubernetes. And I totally forgot about it.

Will upgrade my RAM and get back to work.

Thank you all.